# Fuseki charset issue

Tags: character-encoding, sparql, fuseki

There is a strange problem: insert the data encoded as UTF-8:

```
INSERT DATA { <http://onto.pro/Test> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "Проверка" }
```

then extract them:

```
SELECT * WHERE { <http://onto.pro/Test> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?a }
```

and the encoding is broken:

```
{ "head": { "vars": [ "a" ] } , "results": {  "bindings": [ {  "a": { "type": "literal" , "value": "????????" }  } ] } }
```

As can be seen, instead of "Проверка" returned "????????". The problem occurs suddenly and disappears after restart Fuseki. Where to dig?

Comment: Are incorrect characters actually being returned, or is whatever text editor/console/web browser/etc. in which you're seeing the results just printing `??????` because it doesn't know how to display the bytes it got?

Comment: I see incorrect characters in any way - console or browser, while the locale is set as UTF8.